# Proper incrementing

Tags: javascript, html, loops, increment

I am trying to call a function so that when I click on the button it increments until 1,000,000 and then displays it. However when I call it the incrementation only goes to 9627. I can't put my finger on what the problem is.

```html
<body>
  <script>
    var counter = 0;

    function count() {

      counter++;
      document.getElementById('display').value = counter;
      for (var i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) count(i);

    }
  </script>

  <div>
    <center>
      <button onclick="count();">Let's Count to 1,000,000</button>
      <input type="number" id="display" value="0"></input>
    </center>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You have a recursion problem. You call count inside count. This is also what the error is trying to tell you `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Comment: You are recursively calling the function one million times. Which is then recursively calling the function one million times. Which is then recursively calling the function one million times...

Comment: You should read the console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

You're using recursion for the function, and nested scopes are only supported up to a point (that's why you get stuck at ~10k; google "maximum call stack" for further info).

To fix the problem I'd simply throw the recursion away, and just update the counter. The issue with this is that the loop runs pretty fast, and thus the counter will only be updated once it reaches 1M (immediately subsequent changes to an element's value are optimized by the browser, which hangs waiting for the last `element.value` call before actually re-rendering).

```
<body>


  <script>
      
    function count() {
          
        var counter = 0; // Putting the counter in here makes the counting repeatable

        for (var i = 1; i <= 1_000_000; i++) {
            counter++;
            document.getElementById('display').value = counter;
        }
    }

  </script>


<div>
    <center>
      <button onclick="count();">Let's Count to 1,000,000</button>
      <input type="number" id="display" value="0"></input>
    </center>

</div>


</body>
```

Alternatively, if you want the counter to not go as fast as possible (depending on hardware it should never take > 3s to do at max speed), you can use `setInterval`, or, as referenced by Kinglish in another answer, `setTimeout`.
Here's a snippet with `setInterval`:

```
<body>


  <script>

    function count() {

        var counter = 0;

        var incrementer = setInterval(() => {
            // here "incrementer" gets assigned the id of setInterval,
            // that will later be used to clear the interval
            counter++;
            document.getElementById("display").value = counter;
            if (counter >= 1_000_000) {
                clearInterval(incrementer);
            }
        }, 1000 / 30);
        // the second number (30) represents the times the function will
        // be called per second

    }

  </script>


<div>
    <center>
      <button onclick="count();">Let's Count to 1,000,000</button>
      <input type="number" id="display" value="0"></input>
    </center>

</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the way you have this structured is causing a recursion loop which is throwing a Max call stack error. Here's an alternate way, using `setTimeout`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

```js
let counter = 0, d = document.querySelector('#display');

function count() {
  d.value = counter;
  if (++counter < 1000000) setTimeout(() => {
    count()
  }, 1);

}
```

```html
<div>
  <center>
    <button onclick="count();">Let's Count to 1,000,000</button>
    <input type="number" id="display" value="0"></input>
  </center>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop, it will take a good 5 seconds to reach 1 million but it works:

```html
<body>
  <script>
    var counter = 0;

    function count() {
      var counter = 0;
      for (var i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        document.getElementById('display').value = i;
      }
      

    }
  </script>

  <div>
    <center>
      <button onclick="count();">Let's Count to 1,000,000</button>
      <input type="number" id="display" value="0"></input>
    </center>

  </div>
</body>
```